# I'm a little confused by html entity encoding

Tags: php, html-encode, encoder

So I know this

`string HTML entities ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 [, string $encoding = ini_get("default_charset") [, bool $double_encode = true ]]] )`

is supposed to encode **HTML** entities but I can't seem to get it to work. So basically what I'm trying to ask is, can someone please explain to me how to use this?

The page on PHP's website isn't making much sense to me.

Comment: Where's your code which __not work__?

Comment: string HTML entities ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 [, string $encoding = ini_get("default_charset") [, bool $double_encode = true ]]] )

Comment: This is __function definition__ and not your code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm asking how to make it work because I don't understand it what so ever

Comment: Write some code and see what's happening, no?

Comment: [This](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php#refsect1-function.htmlentities-examples) does not help…?

Comment: If you need conceptual background, http://kunststube.net/escapism might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below example

```
$str = "Jane & 'Tarzan'";
echo htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_COMPAT); // Will only convert double quotes

$str = 'I love "PHP".';
echo htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES); // Converts double and single quotes
```

Comment: The first one also notably converts `&`…